# Why this message appeared when I run the code

Tags: xcode, flutter

I just started to publish my application into apple store.I've encountered few errors that make it unsuccessful to validate the app (Assertion Failure).

Image show the error that i got after run the code inside XCode
[image]

I already try few solution, but still can't solve the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this type of errors are solved after run 'Product' / 'Clean Build Folder' in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I try to clean the build folder already, but it seem like it not helping. It still prompt me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error so far it doesn't affect the performance of the application. And I just untick the metal API validation in Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Diagnostics > Metal Api Validation and it works like a charm. Not to forget to Clean Build Folder of your project and run it again. Hope this solution help others in future.